# does someone know why after i decrypt file it breaks?

Tags: python

```
import os
def encrypt(filename,extension):
    file = open(filename+'.'+extension,'r',encoding="Latin-1")
    red = str(file.read())
    final = [extension+'Q']
    fin = ''
    for x in range(len(red) - 1):
        if red[x] == '0':
            final.append('#!#')
        else:
            final.append(red[x])
    for x in final:
        fin += x
    file.close()
    os.system('del '+filename+'.'+extension)
    file = open(filename,'a')
    file.close()
    file = open(filename,'w',encoding="Latin-1")
    file.write(fin)
    file.close()
def decrypt(filename):
    ignore = 0
    file = open(filename,'r',encoding="Latin-1")
    dat = str(file.read())
    final = []
    fin = ''
    exten = ''
    is_done = False
    for x in range(len(dat) - 1):
        if dat[x] == '#' and dat[x + 1] == '!' and dat[x + 2] == '#' and ignore == 0:
            final.append('0')
            ignore = 2
        elif ignore == 0 and is_done == True:
            final.append(dat[x])
        elif not ignore < 1:
            ignore -= 1
        if dat[x] == 'Q':
            is_done = True
        if is_done == False:
            exten += dat[x]
    for x in final:
        fin += x
    print(filename)
    print(exten)
    file.close()
    file = open(filename+'.'+exten,'a')
    file.close()
    file = open(filename+'.'+exten,'w',encoding="Latin-1")
    file.write(str(fin))
    file.close()
    os.system('del '+filename)
decrypt('eee')
#encrypt('eee','png')
#print(open('test.docx','r',encoding="Latin-1").readlines())
#print(open('eee.png','r',encoding='latin-1').read())
```

i just want it to work as i expect to work and i dont have idea what breaks it help btw when i open files with notepad it looks same so idk whats wrong at all thats weird , sorry for that my code is messy XD thats how my every code looks like

Comment: what actually `breaks`?

Comment: We don't know what you mean by "it breaks".  If you're getting errors, or unexpected results, post those in the question.

Comment: code breaks the file that is being encrypted / decrypted

Comment: like if im encrypting image and decrypting it it just wont open again

Comment: Images are binary files.  I don't believe that converting the file contents to a string with `dat = str(file.read())` is the right way to do it...

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by it 'breaks'? What I'm seeing in your code is:

1. When you run `open(filename,...)`, you assume `file` is correctly holding the file object. You have no error-checking in either `encrypt()` or `decrypt()`. After those lines, read the documentation for the function and see what it returns. You should be able to do something in the lines of:

```
try:
  file = open(filename,'r',encoding="Latin-1")
except err:
  ...

#  start file operations here.
```

File handling can and will go wrong at some point. You can give the program any file that you can specify, but you need to make sure that operation will run successfully. Common file errors are it not existing, being already open, or the permissions being wrong

2. In both `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` you repeat this block:

```
os.system('del '+filename+'.'+extension)
file = open(filename,'a')
file.close()
file = open(filename,'w',encoding="Latin-1")
file.write(fin)
file.close()
```

where you tell the system to **DELETE** your file and then re-open it. I suspect that is a part of why you have issues with the file. I'd also consider removing the second `close()` & `open()` calls to see if you can change the mode without manipulating the file pointer. If this block of code has to be in both parts, separate it into its own function. And run error handling on **Everything**.

Comment: im still getting 'failed to load image' if im trying to open it after encrypting and decrypting it and i did what u told to do so idk